# find matrix derivative with det

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Can't find derivative of `det(X'AX)`.

I try use chain rule like $$\nabla_X f =  det(X'AX) (X'AX)^{-T} [X'AX]$$ as $\nabla_X detX = detX \cdot X^{-T}$, but last two multipliers lead to 4th order tensors and I don't know where I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a new matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\op{sym}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
Y &\equiv X^TAX \\
dY &= \LR{X^TA\;dX+dX^TAX} \\
}$$
Then differentiate the function
$$\eqalign{
f &= \det(Y) \\
df &= f\; Y^{-T}:dY \\
 &= f\;Y^{-T}:\LR{X^TA\;dX+dX^TAX} \\
 &= f\;Y^{-T}:\LR{X^TA\;dX} + \LR{f\;Y^{-T}}^T:\LR{X^TA^T\,dX}^T \\
 &= f\;Y^{-T}:\LR{X^TA\;dX} + f\;Y^{-1}:\LR{X^TA^T\,dX} \\
 &= \LR{f\;A^TXY^{-T}}:dX + \LR{f\;AXY^{-1}}:dX \\
 &= \LR{f\;A^TXY^{-T}+f\;AXY^{-1}}:dX \\
\grad{f}{X}\;
 &= \;{f\;A^TXY^{-T}+f\;AXY^{-1}} \\
}$$
where the matrix inner product has been denoted by a colon
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \} \\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= A:\LR{CB^T} \;=\; B:\LR{A^TC} \\
}$$

---

In *Matrix Calculus* the chain rule is impractical because it involves higher-order tensors. These tensors have no intrinsic interest, they are just quantities that **must** be calculated in order to apply the chain rule.

Furthermore, these tensors are awkward to write using standard matrix notation and require the introduction of special contraction products in order to effectively manipulate them.

By contrast, the differential of a matrix behaves like a matrix.
In particular, it obeys all of the rules of *Matrix Algebra*.

Comment: thank you to correct my wrong understanding of matrix derivatives. Couple questions: 

1. why is $df = fY^{-1} : dY$? Is it general rule? 

2. what does `sym()` mean? Is it operator? 

3. how I can interpret final answer? I try to compare it with [matrix calc](https://www.matrixcalculus.org) answer: $AX \cdot adj(X'AX) + A'X \cdot adj((AX)'X)$

Comment: I had assumed that $A$ was symmetric. I have modified the post to remove that assumption and the `sym()` operator as well.  (1) that is a famous result known as Jacobi's formula, (2) the result from the website is correct, just substitute $\:\operatorname{adj}(Y)=Y^{-1}\det(Y)\;$